# "Connection not open" error when subscribing to address with websocket

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, websocket

I'm trying to subscribe to transactions sent to or from a particular ethereum address. I also want to test this in a local private network, which is why I'm not using etherscan or something like that.

I start geth with this command: `geth --ws --mine --minerthreads=1 --datadir ./test/testDataDir/ --networkid 15`

I connect to the geth console with this command: `geth attach ipc:./test/testDataDir/geth.ipc`

Then I unlock the account and submit a transaction, like this:

`web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:"0x3e1127Bf1A673D378a8570f7a79cEA4F10E20489", value: 100})
"0xe122a9fa56068f9c10802bf607b572d57de83022f6b46238b6a96629c5a0478e"`

This is the output of the miner:

`INFO [07-03|11:18:04] Successfully sealed new block            number=1846 hash=fe4bcc…c4eea9
INFO [07-03|11:18:04]  block reached canonical chain          number=1841 hash=a45268…7aee1b
INFO [07-03|11:18:04]  mined potential block                  number=1846 hash=fe4bcc…c4eea9
INFO [07-03|11:18:04] Commit new mining work                   number=1847 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=160.998µs
INFO [07-03|11:18:05] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xe122a9fa56068f9c10802bf607b572d57de83022f6b46238b6a96629c5a0478e recipient=0x3e1127Bf1A673D378a8570f7a79cEA4F10E20489
INFO [07-03|11:18:14] Successfully sealed new block            number=1847 hash=76f3ee…169d0f
INFO [07-03|11:18:14]  block reached canonical chain          number=1842 hash=d170fb…84b87e
INFO [07-03|11:18:14]  mined potential block                  number=1847 hash=76f3ee…169d0f
INFO [07-03|11:18:14] Commit new mining work                   number=1848 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=233.923µs`

Here's how I connect to web3 from my code:

`const Web3 = require('web3'); //1.0.0-beta.34
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
}
else {
    web3 = new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8546');
}`

And here's where I subscribe to the logs. I want to have a callback whenever a transaction is sent to a particular address.

`var options = {
    fromBlock: '0x0',
    address: '0x3e1127Bf1A673D378a8570f7a79cEA4F10E20489'
};
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options, function(error, result){
    if(error || result == null){
        console.log('Error when watching incoming transactions: ', error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Got something back: ', result);
    // code continues...
}
subscription.on('data', function(log){
    console.log(log);
});`

But this is what gets printed on the console from my code:

`connection not open on send()
Error when watching incoming transactions:  connection not open
connection not open on send()
Error when watching incoming transactions:  connection not open
connection not open on send()
Error when watching incoming transactions:  connection not open
connection not open on send()
Error when watching incoming transactions:  connection not open`

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Perhaps I'm not connecting to the websocket correctly.

Comment: So I got what I wanted by subscribing to `pendingTransactions` and then checking if the transaction was sent to an address I have stored in an array. I think under the hood, subscribing to an individual address probably does something similar so it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
geth --ws  --wsaddr "0.0.0.0" --wsapi "eth,net,web3,admin,shh" --wsorigins "*"  --mine --minerthreads=1 --datadir ./test/testDataDir/ --networkid 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The error goes away, but instead it doesn't print anything at all.